# How to get the source code after doing a repo sync?

Tags: git, repository, gitorious, tizen

I am downloading the source of tizen OS from gitorious using git.
I downloaded the Repo script and ensured it is executable by the command:

```
 $ curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/googlesource/git-repo/repo > ~/bin/repo
 $ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
```

Then I ran repo init by specifying a tizen-manifest URL for the manifest.

```
 $ repo init -u git://gitorious.org/tizen-toys/tizen-manifest
```

Then to pull down files to my working directory from the repositories as specified in the tizen-manifest I've initialized, I used

```
 $ repo sync
```

I got GBs of data. But those are not source files. How do I convert it into source files ?

Comment: Have you asked the guys of Tizen? that would be the first place to ask, since they work with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After repo sync, it will perform a checkout to get all the source codes. so we ll get source codes. This will happen only after finishing the repo sync, if repo sync got stuck in between, we can resume it by doing another repo sync. it will not start from the beginning

Comment: which takes days maybe weeks!